# Turning on Bluetooth headphones resets keyboard

Tags: keyboard, mouse, bluetooth, bluez, usbhid

I have a pair of Bluetooth noise canceling headphones (Bose QC 35s if that's important) and whenever I turn them on they cause my keyboard and mouse settings to be reset back to default, which is thoroughly annoying.

I assume something in the Human Interface Device code is causing this to happen but it's not clear to me what is doing it or why.

I've looked at the Bluetooth transactions with **wireshark** but I confess that I'm not entirely certain what I'm looking at, since I'm not a Bluetooth expert.

I've written a rather simpleminded **python** script that monitors the DBus **org.bluez** bus for a **PropertiesChanged** signal and that works but it's something of a kludge and it offends my sense of order and completeness that I have to resort to it.

If anyone has any suggestion on configuration of **bluez** or **DBus** that I should be looking at, I'd be appreciative.

I'm running Ubuntu 19.04 if that's at all relevant (it's been a long term issue, so I doubt it).

Comment: I have this problem as well.  If I change the keyboard to Russian (say) with `setxkbmap ru`, then connect my bluetooth headset, the keyboard layout reverts to the normal (I guess the one I get on login).  My workaround is to map a key to change the layout to the one that I want.